# Dynamic storage provisioning on single bare metal node

Tags: dynamic, kubernetes, storage, kubernetes-statefulset

Is there a way to achieve dynamic storage provisioning on a single, bare metal, kubernetes node? I need the storage volumes to be dynamically provisioned for StatefulSet with multiple replicas.

Because I haven't found one yet.

- [glusterfs](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/setup-guide.md) requires at least 3 nodes
- [nfs](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/nfs/docs/deployment.md#in-kubernetes---statefulset-of-1-replica) does not support multiple replicas
- [hostPath](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/local-volume#future-features) does not support dynamic provisioning

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this? Facing same need.